# Best Way For Data Storage On Simple Data

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, file

I need a data storage (with CRUD) on a web application for a simple data `structure (key, value)`, what is best choice for speed and stability:

1. Advanced database like SQL Server
2. Other database like SQLite
3. File Text Manipulation
4. something else....

Thanks.

Comment: We don't really have enough requirements at the moment. What's the scalability requirement? Is this sensitive data? Read-only, or read-write? How much will there be? What operations do you need?

Comment: @Jon Skeet, what about SQLServer Compact? http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/compact.aspx . It is not scalable horinzontaly....

Comment: @danihp: Without knowing the requirements, it's impossible to say whether or not that would be a good fit.

Comment: i explain my problem briefly, my requirement is a data storage for a simple data that include (key,value) for example,word dictionary. and speed is important too.Meanwhile CRUD(create-read-update-delete)=read-write

Comment: excuse me for my bad english language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend save the information in a Xml file [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/xml_serializationasp.aspx) you can find good info

Comment: Without knowing more about the requirements, we can't tell whether or not that's a good fit.

Comment: XML is great for **data exchange** - but it sucks for storage. It tends to be huge in size (bloated) and doesn't really offer any benefit over e.g. SQLite....

Comment: I know,but he said he needs a simple storage